# Run Makefile target inside of docker

Tags: docker, makefile

I am having trouble running make targets inside of Dockerfile. I am also not sure if I should be using `bash` or `alpine` as a base of my image.

Makefile:

```
all:
    echo "all target is working"

test:
    echo "test target is working"

build:
    echo "build target is working"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bash:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/program

COPY Makefile Makefile
```

Testing:

```
docker build . -t program
docker run program "make test"
```

Error:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 11: exec: more Makefile: not found

Comment: When formatting errors and other cut/pasted content in StackOverflow please don't use quoted paragraph formats.  That is meant for written text, not code.  That will re-wrap all your lines and this makes it hard to decipher error messages.

Comment: The error message looks like you ran `docker run program "more Makefile"`. The quotes are wrong there as well.

Comment: I'd suggest `ubuntu` as a base image here, but also conversely avoiding bash-specific syntax when possible.  If you're building a C application the toolchain is _huge_, and saving a couple of megabytes in the smaller `alpine` base image at the cost of some binary compatibility isn't a great trade-off (you won't notice that the image is 500 instead of 550 MB, but you might notice strange dynamic-library errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are wrong. You want simply

```
docker run program make test
```

Which base image to use depends entirely on what the `Makefile` tries to do. Unless you are specifically trying to do something specific to Bash, probably the base `alpine` image is a good starting point.